# Geodesic lines of the form f(at+b)

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Assume a two dimensional surface $\Sigma$ parametrized by $f:U\rightarrow\Sigma$,  where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $ \Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.
Show that if for every $a,b \in \mathbb{R^2}$, $\gamma(t)=f(at+b)$ is a geodesic line then $\Sigma$ is isometric to a part of a plane.

I have tried working with geodesic equations but no luck so far. I feel like i lack some basic understanding, so references to good notes on the subject will be appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about this theorem ?recall Klein modell of the hyperbolic plane (space) whose all geodesics are lines of the disc.

Comment: In Klein model straight lines in Sigma are geodesic. This question is about images of straight lines. For example, geodesic lines on a cylinder are images of straight lines on a plane.

Comment: But a cylinder is flat, whereas the hyperbolic plane is not. The Beltrami surface is (at least locally) a modell of the hyperbolic plane, therefore admit local charts for which all the lines are geodesics.

Comment: Ok i see now that i didn't translate the question right. I need to show that Sigma is isometric to a part of a plane. Sorry about that, i wasn't aware to the meaning of "flat surface".

Comment: But flat = locally isometric to a part of a surface.